# is there a Java WebSocket server library to push notification to a JavaScript Client?

Tags: javascript, java, sockets, websocket

I'm trying to make a connection between clients and server to push notifications while offline and only could find Atmosphere library which had some problems on installation related to ServeLet.

Is there any Java server library I can use to implement it?

Comment: What about https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/stomp.html

Comment: Have you tried achieving push notification using this?

Comment: try https://socket.io/

Comment: I want a WebSocket library with fallback options to other realtime protocols